# asp.net core 2.1 ConfigurationBuilder GetSection function return null

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

ConfigurationBuilder Getsection() return null on .net core 2.1 console application. I have been searched quite a few blogs and posts but there is json example where its nested upto 3-4 levels.

Motive is to read the whole "test" key of json and its elements and do operations. I want this json to be configurable outside the application, so it can be changed without making any changes in code.
Below is the sample code

```
{
  "test": {
    "test1": {
      "testing": {
        "ApplicationName": "Microsoft Visual Studio", 
        "appid": "123456", 
        "ApplicationProfile": {
          "Vs2015": "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Professional",
          "VS_2017_Restricted": "Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (Restricted)"
        }
      }
      },
      "Applications": {
        "app1": {
          "Name": "application1",
          "arrayOfSomething": [ "first array elment", "Secondarrayelement" ],
          "anotherarraylikeabove": [],

        },
        "app2": {
          "Name": "application2",
          "Softwares": [ "first array elment", "second element" ],
          "APACGroups": [],
          "EMEA": [],
          "OnlyForZurich": [] 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
var test  = configuration.GetSection("app2"); //test is null always
```

Comment: `app2` is under `test/Applications/app2`. You will need to get the parent sections first. `configuration.GetSection("test").GetSection("Applications").GetSection("app2")`

Comment: Furthering on from this, you have an extra bracket at the end. Malformed JSON.

Comment: To read the array element one have to do this:
configuration.GetSection("test").GetSection("Applications").GetSection("app2").GetSection("Softwares")
                .GetChildren().ToArray().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();

Answer (score 3):

use this one maybe it work:

json:

```
   "Locations": {
        "Location": [ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
    },
```

startup:

```
 // Replace IConfiguration with IHostingEnvironment since we will build
    // Our own configuration
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        // Set the new Configuration
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

and get data from:

```
 public IActionResult Settings()
    {
       var array = Configuration.GetSection("Locations:Location")
           .GetChildren()
           .Select(configSection => configSection.Value);
       return View();
    }
```

Comment: not useful in my case not able to read, array declared in my json

Comment: To read the array element one have to do this:
configuration.GetSection("test").GetSection("Applications").GetSection("app2").GetSection("Softwares")
                .GetChildren().ToArray().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();